# Optimization problem for S-I-S model using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a susceptible-infectious-susceptible model,

[image]

to which I've written the following python code,

```py
def SIS(I0, beta, gamma, N=2000):
    f1 = N - I0

    f2 = -beta * I0
    f2 /= N
    f2 = 1 - exp(f2)

    f3 = gamma * I0

    return (f1 * f2) - f3 + I0
```

And I'm solving it using the following code,

```py
I0, beta, gamma, N = 10, 0.2, 0.25, 2000

t = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)

inf = [I0]

for i in t[:-1]:
    inf.append(SIS(inf[-1], beta, gamma))
```

This part is fine. I'm having trouble finding the double derivative [image] and optimizing it for the value of the `beta` parameter. The problem is that the beta is not given and since that parameter is within the exponential function, it doesn't make sense to me to be able to get to the 10th value of the infectious parameter and then equate it to 0 to solve. I'm only given [image: parameters] for this particular problem.

If someone can guide me in the correct direction, that'd be a great help.

Comment: Do you want to numerically approximate the derivate or find it symbolically?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to approximate it numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) to approximate the derivate. An example for the second derivative:

```
h = 0.0001
t = 10
I_left   = solve(I0, t, beta-h, gamma, N)
I_right  = solve(I0, t, beta+h, gamma, N)
I_center = solve(I0, t, beta, gamma, N)

d2I_dB2 = (I_right - I_center + I_left) / h**2
```

where `solve` solves the recurrence up to `t`.

Comment: But this still requires the value of the `beta` parameter. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, but for this specific problem, I'm not given the `beta`. I have to determine/find the value that maximizes that `I_10` double derivative.

Comment: Did they give any more direction than that? There are hundreds of optimization methods out there - or it could be as simple as trying many betas in a feasible interval and picking the best.

Comment: I see, I can try the second approach. because there has to be some `beta` to satisfy it.